# Middle char to upper case in java

Tags: java

```
StringBuffer strbuff=new StringBuffer("Hello students");
char ch=strb.charAt(9).toUpperCase();
```

It's not working - I want to convert the character at 10 location `toUppercase()`. How can I do this?

Comment: did you even check what error you got in console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`toUpperCase()` is method of String/Character class, it cannot be applied to a native char type.**

**PS:** Note that `strbuff.charAt(9)` will return you a `char` and to covert that to upper case you will need to call [**`Character.toUpperCase(char)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29) like this:

This should work instead:

```
StringBuffer strbuff=new StringBuffer("Hello students");
char ch=Character.toUpperCase(strbuff.charAt(9));
System.out.println(ch); // D
```

**If you want to set this back in StringBuffer:**

```
strbuff.setCharAt(9, ch);
```

Comment: `toUpperCase() is method of String class` - But you just called `toUpperCase()` of `Character` class

Comment: @Rajesh: `Character.toUpperCase()` is a static method but `String#toUpperCase()` is not. See my example above.

Comment: I am aware of that. Your edit `toUpperCase() is method of String/Character class` is fine now

Answer (score 4):

I assue you want to modify your string:

```
StringBuffer strbuff=new StringBuffer("Hello students");
strbuff.setCharAt(9, Character.toUpperCase(strbuff.charAt(9)));
```

Hint 1: In case you are on a current Java version, use `StringBuilder`, unless you need Thread-safety.

Hint 2: You cannot invoke a method on a `char` because it is a primitive type, that is why you use the static `Character#toUpperCase` method.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need I guess,

```
char ch=Character.toUpperCase(strbuff.charAt(9));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char ch=strb.charAt(9).toUpperCase();
```

REPLACE THIS BY

```
char ch=Character.toUpperCase(strbuff.charAt(9));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `StringBuffer` is named `strbuff`, but you're accessing an (undefined) `strb` on the second line.

And even if that was just a typo, the second line does nothing but create a new variable `ch`, but it doesn't use that to construct a new string.